# Java refresh program elements

Tags: java

Quick question. I have a program that can write to a file using a `Buffered writer` and then retrieves that written information in the program using a `Scanner`.

The problem I am having is when I create a new entry to the text file, the scanner won't pick that newly entered information unless I close the program and re-open it.

Is there some sort of way I can refresh the JFrame/Scanner/Class when I post the data?

Comment: Did you flush your writer?

Comment: You are probably not calling `close()` after finishing writing. `close()` will flush and close the stream.

Comment: @dambros I have closed it.

Comment: Are you re-assigning the scanner between reads, in order to get a new underlying input stream ?